# Microsoft Azure OAuth 2.0 Authentication failed

Tags: oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, jakarta-mail

Szenario:

I am in the process of writing a Java application which should reads email messages from a personal Microsoft Outlook account (Microsoft 365 Family).

In the Azure portal, an app is registered ("Applications from personal account"):

The API permissions are set to:

- IMAP.AccessAsUser.all
- Mail.ReadWrite
- POP.AccessAsUser.all
- User.Read
- (all "Admin consent required = No")

A client secret was created

- The Java connect thru Jakarta Mail returns "A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed"

Steps:

- The OAuth 2.0 authorization is successful with the following parameters:
- URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token/
- Scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

The client credential flow is successful and returns a Bearer token

- The application uses the Java Jakarta Mail API with the following properties set:

```
Mail property mail.imaps.auth.login.disabe: true
Mail property mail.imaps.auth.plain.disable: true
Mail property mail.debug.auth.password: false
Mail property mail.mime.ignoreunknownencoding: true
Mail property mail.imaps.port: 993
Mail property mail.imaps.sasl.mechanisms: XOAUTH2
Mail property mail.store.protocol: imaps
Mail property mail.imaps.ssl.enable: true
Mail property mail.imaps.partialfetch: false
Mail property mail.mime.decodetext.strict: false
Mail property mail.debug.auth: true
Mail property mail.imaps.peek: true
Mail property mail.imaps.sasl.enable: true
```

- Jakarta Mail debug file:

```
DEBUG: setDebug: Jakarta Mail version 1.6.7
DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imaps,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPSSLStore,Oracle]
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.partialfetch: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
DEBUG IMAPS: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
DEBUG IMAPS: enable SASL
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL mechanisms allowed: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: peek
DEBUG IMAPS: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
DEBUG IMAPS: trying to connect to host "outlook.office365.com", port 993, isSSL true
* OK The Microsoft Exchange IMAP4 service is ready. [WgBSADAAUAAyADcAOABDAEEAMAAwADQANwAuAEMASABFAFAAMgA3ADgALgBQAFIATwBEAC4ATwBVAFQATABPAE8ASwAuAEMATwBNAA==]
A0 CAPABILITY
* CAPABILITY IMAP4 IMAP4rev1 AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=XOAUTH2 SASL-IR UIDPLUS ID UNSELECT CHILDREN IDLE NAMESPACE LITERAL+
A0 OK CAPABILITY completed.
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: PLAIN
DEBUG IMAPS: AUTH: XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: protocolConnect login, host=outlook.office365.com, user=xxxxxx@outlook.com, password=<non-null>
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL Mechanisms:
DEBUG IMAPS:  XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: 
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL client XOAUTH2
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL callback length: 2
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL callback 0: javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback@aba95da8
DEBUG IMAPS: SASL callback 1: javax.security.auth.callback.PasswordCallback@f96503dd
A1 AUTHENTICATE XOAUTH2 dXNlcj1hbmR5....................RWpfQncBAQ==
A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed.
```

- The passed string "dxNl.....AQ==" can be Base64-decoded and shows the correct syntax.
- What could cause this authentication error?

Thanks a lot for any pointer
Andy

**Update**

I also changed the application type to "All Microsoft account users" without success.

The API permissions are set to

[image]

The OAuth 2.0 parameters are

Authorization URL: https://login.microsoftonline.com/consumers/oauth2/v2.0/token/
Authorization Scope: https://outlook.office.com/.default

I do get a Bearer token but it is not valid for MS 365 Family and Java Jakarta Mail.

Answer (score 0):

The **A1 NO AUTHENTICATE failed** error is being caused by an **access token not issued for the proper resource+scope set**.

Please replace scope https://graph.microsoft.com/.default with https://outlook.office.com/.default.

For more information take a look to [Get an access token in Authenticate an IMAP, POP or SMTP connection using OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/legacy-protocols/how-to-authenticate-an-imap-pop-smtp-application-by-using-oauth#get-an-access-token)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help! I changed the scope but the authentication still fails (see update above)